# LT3751 voltage never increases

Tags: voltage

I am using LT3751 for the first time, tried alot but no luck need help.

I am using the chip in regulation mode and following the circuit given in datasheet on page number 26 with title "High Voltage Regulator."

I want to generate 500V but the problem is the output is stuck at 260V.  It never increases above no matter what I change in the circuit.

Few observations on oscilloscope to share:

1- At startup there is spike of 2.48V on FB pin which falls down and reaches to 1 volt.

2- FB pin is always noisy.

3- At load greater than 20K after around 100 ms fault pin goes low. At 16.6K load 260V is sustained. Does the chip require some minimum load for operation?

Following are my specifications:

Vtrans =  28V

Vcc     = 22V

C2     = 0.22uF 50V

RBG, RVout, Clamp pins are GND with 0 ohm resistor.

Output capacitor (C4) = 100uF 900V

M1 NMOS (MOSFET) = IRF510

C10 = 1uF 25V

R1 and R3 = 100K

R2 and R4 = 600K

D1 = 8S2TH061

Charge pin is pulsed using RC circuit.

Rest is same as the circuit in the [datasheet.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt3751.pdf)

Circuit diagram:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a GROUND PLANE?

Comment: First step is to remedy the fault condition of the regulator.

Comment: @sidk A fault is triggered by any of the UVLO/OVLO comparators. Can you include a table of what thresholds you calculated?

Comment: Fault is continously high my lower and upper threshold is set to 6V to 36V.

Comment: Okay, you indicated in your question the regulator faults out. It could be PCB layout, voltage coefficient of ceramic caps, component choices etc.

Comment: Yeah but at loads less than 16k fault remains high and voltage 250v is constant. Why it doesn't increase.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the most important things at all:

Values for R10 and R11.

For 500V output, R10 needs to be 715k and R11 needs to be 1.74k.

RBG is R9, and you have that properly a zero ohms.

All that is in the chart right there with the diagram on page 26:

[image]

The datasheet doesn't mention a minimum load.  But, since the chart doesn't go all the way to 0 for higher Vtrans it may have trouble regulating the output voltage for low loads.  Or, the fault pin is reacting to the load changes because you haven't set up the regulator properly.

Check and fix the configuration (R10, R11, and compare the rest of your circuit with the recommendations.)

Once it reaches the **designed** output voltage you can repeat your load tests.

Comment: Using  values for R10 and R11 715k and 1.78k recpectively. Output is 250 not increasing. Any idea pkz?

Comment: a - Can i use any value of R10 and R11 to generate 1.213829283 or the Datasheet suggest values are mandatory? 


b - analogsystemsrf : No, we are not using Any GND plane, Yes there is thermal pad below the IC and the MOSFET as recommended in the Datasheet

Comment: Any Help please??